# How to convert C to Assembly, for a program that runs on the ATmega32U4 (connected to a Teensy 2.0)

Tags: c, assembly, translate, atmega

I've created some simple code in C that changes the duty cycle of the output and I'm trying to translate it to Assembly so that I can edit it there and increase efficiency. However, the code is written for an Atmega32U4 connected to a Teensy 2.0, and whenever I try to translate it across using common methods, it throws me errors as a result of the libraries being used (I think).

If I knew how to write in Assembly, I would redo this entire code, but I'm fairly clueless there.

The code is as follows,

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 7800UL                // frequency of 7.8kHz
#include <util/delay.h>

int main()
{
DDRF = 0x00;            // all in F are input
PORTF = 0xFF;           // all inputs are set to low
DDRB = 0xFF;            // all in B are output
PORTB = 0x00;

while(1)
    {
    if (~PINF &(1<<PF1))            // 0.05 duty cycle
        {
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(50);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(950);
        }
    else if (~PINF & (1<<PF4))      //0.73 duty cycle
        {
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(730);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(270);
        }
    else if (~PINF & (1<<PF6))      //0.92 duty cycle
        {
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(920);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(80);
        }
    else
        {
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I haven't coded this in the most efficient or correct manner, but I've only been learning C for the last month. Any advice in translating this to Assembly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For accuracy and efficency, you can use a timer or PWN output function instead. That will be easier and more maintainable.

Comment: Refer to the user manual or datasheet to see whether your microcontroller has `PWM` output function. Then use it. If it doesn't, you could implement a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or use multiple timers to achieve different duty cycles.

Answer (score 1):

If your code can be compiled (if the errors you mention are linker and not compiler errors) you can compile to assembler.

Most C compilers use the "-S" or "-s" command line option to create an assembler file instead of an object file.

Some hint: Most C compilers do not support binary numbers like 0b00100000. Maybe you should use hexadecimal numbers instead - at least to be compatible with other compilers.